# If / Else jQuery to parse against a list of zip codes

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement, zip

I'm trying to write a price quote estimator that utilizes an array of zip codes to be a service area.  The list of zip codes is rather extensive, so I don't know if it is better or an option at all to have an external source, such as a CSV.

What I would like is for people to enter their zip codes, and if it is on the list, they will be given the price calculator option.

If their zip code is not on the list, a message should appear of "Please Call for More Info"

I am sort of frankensteining code right now, but this is what I have:

```
$(function(){
var zipCodes = ['92056', '90210', '92121', '92101','19148'];
$('#id_div_one, #id_div_two').hide();
if(jQuery.inArray(zipCodes) > -1) {
$('#id_div_one').css('display', 'inline');
} else {
$('#id_div_two').css('display', 'inline');
}
return false;
});
```

And then this is the div:

```
<form  id="zip_form">
Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="id_zip_code"><input type="submit"    
value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="id_div_one">[CP_CALCULATED_FIELDS id="6"]</div>
<div id="id_div_two">Please call our office for a quote</div>
```

I had it working where submit was triggering the display of the price calculation plugin, but am not understanding how to work with the if / else to pull from the array.  Any help is greatly appreciated -- I have been scouring the web without much luck.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uazry/1

Comment: That did it -- Thank you, Arun!  You are a terrific help :)

Answer (score 1):

`$.inArray()` **requires** a minimum of 2 arguments - 1) *a value to look for* and 2) *an array to look into*. **[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)**

In your case, you are passing only the value (the first argument as per the signature of `inArray`), what you need is:

```
if(jQuery.inArray($('#id_zip_code').val(), zipCodes) > -1) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense -- Thank you!  It's still not working right with this code added, however, and it is automatically displaying the #id_div_two content.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function(){
    var zipCodes = ['92056', '90210', '92121', '92101','19148'];
    $('#id_div_one, #id_div_two').hide();

    $('#zip_form').submit(function(){
        $('#id_div_one, #id_div_two').hide();
        if(jQuery.inArray($('#id_zip_code').val(), zipCodes) > -1) {
            $('#id_div_one').css('display', 'inline');
        } else {
            $('#id_div_two').css('display', 'inline');
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uazry/)