# Jquery Zip code service area verification woes.

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to validate a form that takes in users zipcodes and tests this against an array of zip codes serviced. I'd like to make it work on submit. Right now it does nothing and throws no errors.. I'm so lost. I'm kind of new to jquery but not programming

```
<DOCTYPE!>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var zipCodeArray = ["98001", "98002", "98003", "98004"];
$("#zipCode").live('keyup', function(){
   var zipCode = $(this).val();
    if(zipCode.length >4){
     if($.inArray(zipCode, zipCodeArray)){
       //do nothing, or do whatever you want
       //we have a return true here.
     }else{
       alert("Sorry. we only offer services western Washington at this time.");
     } 
   }
});    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="zipCode">
<form>
<input id="zipCode" name="zipCode" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783384/if-else-jquery-to-parse-against-a-list-of-zip-codes?rq=1) is where the answer is for anyone else looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
if($.inArray(zipCode, zipCodeArray)){
```

to

```
if($.inArray(zipCode, zipCodeArray) > -1){
```

`$.inArray()` method **returns the index of the element in the array** and not a **boolean value**..

Also you need to encase your code in **DOM Ready handler**, as your script is before the content

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: thank you. I found the solution in the column to the right immediately after posting the question. Your answer was a huge help as well very useful information. Also I have it working without the $(function(){})

Comment: am I using the correct most recent script src learning from the web can lead you down very old paths I noticed some fiddles using a 1.9 version. Thanks again

Comment: Current version is `2.0.2` :)